# PostgreSQL, one-to-many query, without duplicating the one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, one-to-many

Is there a good way to return, in a single query, a one-to-many relation, without sending duplicates of the fields for the tuple on the one side?  Say you have two tables with a typical 1-to-many relation.

```
create table whole (
  id integer,
  comment text  -- can be large value
)
create table part (
  id integer,
  whole integer references whole,
  foo text
)
```

And you want to get all the `whole` objects, along with their zero or more `part`s.  So you do a typical join:

```
select w.id, w.comment, p.id, p.foo
from whole w join part p on w.id = p.whole 
where ...
```

You might get back

```
+---+-------------------+---+------------+
|id |comment            |id |foo         |
+---+-------------------+---+------------+
|1  |'long comment ... '|1  |'part 1 foo'|
+---+-------------------+---+------------+
|1  |'long comment ... '|2  |'part 2 foo'|
+---+-------------------+---+------------+
|2  |...                |...|...         |
+---+-------------------+---+------------+
|...|...                |...|...         |
```

So if the `whole` with `id` of 1 had 100 parts you get 'long comment' going over the wire 100 times.  What's a good way to avoid this, without sending multiple queries through the DB connection?

Comment: You can aggregate the patrs into array or json/xml.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the relational structure does replicate the values in this case.  You could enumerate the values and then choose to send only the first one:

```
select w.id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by w.id order by p.id) = 1 then w.comment
        end) as comment, p.id, p.foo
from whole w join
     part p
     on w.id = p.whole 
where ...
```